# load article inside a page php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how is it possible to achieve this:

http://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/

using php?

let's say that I have the following a url:

http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=pages-folder/works-folder/content-manager?article=my-article

to get there I have a link in pages-folder/works.php :

```
<a href="pages-folder/works-folder/content-manager?article=my-article"> link </a>
```

which should open content-manager.php in which inside a div I should load my-article.php

EDITED:

I have an index file in which a load into the div.container all the pages I need, so in this case my works.php file is loaded int the div.container using using:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if(!empty($page)){
      $page .= '.php';
      include($page);
    }
    else {
      include('pages/home.php');
    }
```

since I also needed to update the url without reloading the page I use this script:

```
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
  if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
    var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
    history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
  }
}

$('ul.menu li a').on('click', function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var pageUrl = page.split("/");
    pageUrl = pageUrl[1];

    $('.container').load(page + '.php', function(){
      //fadeout old content
      //fadein new content
    });

    ChangeUrl('Page1', '?page=' + page);

    return false;
})
```

once I have my works.php loaded into the div.container I have the above mentioned link which should lead me to: pages-folder/works-folder/content-manager.php

it is in this page where I'd like to load my-article.php inside the main div of content-manager.php

I thought that adding the ?article= variable would have worked using the same system as above:

```
$article = $_GET['article'];
if(!empty($article)){
  $article .= '.php';
  include($article);
}
else {
  ...
}
```

but it doesn't...
how can I achieve this?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Anything else? You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and **post what you've tried** with a clear explanation of what **isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i hope it looks better now...

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just add you article as a query param ?

http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=pages-folder/works-folder/content-manager&article=my-article

and make a link like this

```
<a href="pages-folder/works-folder/content-manager&article=<?php echo $_GET['article'] ?>"> link </a>
```

This is just an exemple to understand what you want to do, don't use this kind of code in production, he is vulnerably to CSRF attack

EDIT: with echo it's better sorry

Comment: ahhh you mean using '&' instead of '?' I'll give it a try

Comment: This won't work. You need to echo `$_GET['article']`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't answered your question per se but this is the sort of code you are looking for:

```php
<?php if (isset($_GET["page"]) && strtolower($_GET["page"]) == "1") { ?>
    <p>You are on page one</p>
    <a href="thisPage.php">Back</a>

<?php } elseif (isset($_GET["page"]) && strtolower($_GET["page"]) == "2") { ?>
    <p>You are on page two</p>
    <a href="thisPage.php">Back</a>

<?php } else { ?>
    <p>You have not selected a page. Click one of the links:</p>
    <a href="thisPage.php?page=1">Page one</a>
    <a href="thisPage.php?page=2">Page two</a>
<?php } ?>
```

---

## Explanation

### How does [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) work?

`$_GET` is a [super global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variable - meaning it can be accessed from anywhere.

It is a an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.
These are specified following a question mark (`?`) in the URL. To specify multiple parameters you must use the ampersand (`&`) character between each one.
`$_GET` must be specified at the end of the URL after everything else.

```
http://www.example.com/thisPage.php?page=a
http://www.example.com/thisPage.php?page=a&theme=light
```

The first URL will produce a `$_GET` with one element which can be accessed as: `$_GET["page"]` and would return a string of one character `a`.
The second will produce:

```php
$_GET["page"]; // returns "a"
$_GET["theme"]; // returns "light"
```

Notice that for each parameter a new key-value pair is created.

<sub><sub>I wrote a comprehensive explanation of superglobals on SO Documentation, but that has since been deprecated. RIP my hard work :P</sub></sub>

### Showing differing content

As you can see from my answer above. You can use simple if statements to check what the value is.

Firstly, ensure that `$_GET` `isset` and then check the value.
I have converted the value of the array to lowercase since `"A"` is not the same as `"a"`.

The example you linked to *really over-complicates things*. There is honestly no need for all that regular expressions, and it also relies on JavaScript which is not necessarily a good idea.
With my example at the top, there is no difference between user experience as PHP is server sided thus all the content is worked out and then served to the user.

### One step further

Using this you can go that extra step and have an event listener and combine it with [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp).

Altering my initial example you can have the following.
I have used the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/) as it is a lot easier to implement.

```php
<div id="test">
    <?php if (isset($_GET["page"]) && strtolower($_GET["page"]) == "1") { ?>
        <p>You are on page one</p>
        <a href="t.php">Back</a>

    <?php } elseif (isset($_GET["page"]) && strtolower($_GET["page"]) == "2") { ?>
        <p>You are on page two</p>
        <a href="t.php">Back</a>

    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>You have not selected a page. Click one of the links:</p>
        <a href="t.php?page=1">Page one</a>
        <a href="t.php?page=2">Page two</a>

    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

```js
function myAJAX() {
    $("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the clicked page number
        if (this.href.indexOf("&") > -1) {
            var d = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("page=") + "page=".length, this.href.indexOf("&"))
        } else {
            var d = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf("page=") + "page=".length)
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "t.php",
            data: "page=" + d,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // change the content of the #test div
                $("#test").html($($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#test")[0]);
                myAJAX();
            }
        });
    });
}
myAJAX();
```

Notice that the HTML is not being wrapped in `<div id="test">` which is so that the JavaScript can find that element and change it in the function.
`$("#test").html($($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#test")[0]);` is the line that is fetching the HTML and changing it with the data from the page you tried to click on.
I also call the function inside itself so that it will reattach on the anchor links. If you remove this line then the page will redirect as normal.

The good thing about this implementation is that if your user does not have JavaScript then the page will act as normal and there will be a normal reload of the site.
No need for any extra work on your part.